# Is there any way to preserve my data using 'write.csv' and 'read.csv'?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, xlsx, read.csv

This is my data frame A
column : 7
row :   10000000

I tried to make this data frame into csv file.

```
write.csv(A, file="Bus station.csv")
```

However, the csv file contains only some rows.

```
B <- read.csv("Bus station.csv", header = T, fileEncoding = "euc-kr")
```

dim(B)
column : 8
row :  1048575

I want to preserve this data and make it into new file.
I don't care using any other functions without 'write.csv' or something.

Comment: Excel has a limit of  1048575 rows. The problem is not in R, the problem is when you open the csv file in Excel. As for the extra column, that's a row names column, you can remove it by writing to file with `write.csv(etc, row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: `A -> saveRDS(file = "demo")
A <- readRDS("demo")`